# Flexbox doesn't contain the whole images (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, slider

I'm making a image film with `flexbox` properties for using my own slider script. The issue is when I inspect the `.film` div, it doesn't contain the whole images properly like this:

[image]

As you can see, the images belong to the `.film` div. However, it only contains small piece of the image. I would like the `.film` div covers all of the images.

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

This is the code:

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.film {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  left: -130%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 7.5%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('CovercefwM.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer" draggable="false">
      <div class="film" draggable="false">
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false">
          <!-- <img src="CovercefwM.jpg" alt=""> -->
        </a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false">
          <!-- <img src="Coverdefw.jpg" alt=""> -->
        </a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false">
          <!-- <img src="Covercefw.jpg" alt=""> -->
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: because there is margin in outer

Comment: @NishargShah It doesn't matter about `margin` in the `.outer` div. I'd checked it before.

Answer (score 0):

Set your images css to:

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Flexbox will take care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand from your style how you want the images to be displayed. If you set width: 50%; for the image, and you have 3 of them, than there's no room for all three to fit in the parent div (plus margin of 7.5% on each of them). Also, I see that you want them with space between. You used margin 7.5%, but instead you could use justify-content: space-between; on film, it will have same effect, but better.
As a solution, I would suggest setting width: 30%; and removing the margin 7.5% for .images, instead, setting justify-content: space-between; for .film will do the spacing you want.
I hope that this is the result that you actually wanted. 
Here's the corrected css:

```
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.film {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  left: -130%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('CovercefwM.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```